# How can I create a loop in my program to make it run at the end of each user option in python?

Tags: python

Here is my code:-

```
f= open("Passes.py", "a+")
m=open("money.py","a+")
passes= {}
init={}
initial=0
import time
print "Welcome to the virtual banking system"
user=raw_input("Would you like to create a new account? 'Y/N'").lower()
if user== "y":
  new_user= raw_input("Create a username:")
  new_pass= raw_input("Create a password:")
  p= passes[new_user]= new_user + ":" + new_pass
  f.write("\n"+p)
  ask=raw_input("Would you like to sign into your account? 'Y/N'").lower()
  if ask=="y":
    user_in=raw_input("Enter your username:")
    if user_in==new_user:
      pass_in=raw_input("Enter your password:")
      if pass_in==new_pass:
        print "Welcome to your account" + " " + new_user
        **useropt=raw_input("Would you like to view your balance- enter 1, deposit money- enter 2, withdraw money- enter 3 or exit- enter 4:")**
        if useropt=="1":
          print "Your balance is:", initial
          m.write(str(initial)+"\n")
        if useropt=="2":
          amountdep= int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit?:"))
          initial+=amountdep
          print "Thanks. Your new balance is:", initial
          m.write(str(initial)+"\n")
        if useropt=="3":
          amountwith=int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?:"))
          initial-=amountwith
          print "Your balance is:", initial
          m.write(str(initial)+"\n")
      else:
        print "Password not valid"

    else:
      print "Username does not exist"

  else:
    print "Thanks for using the virtual bank."

else:
  user2=raw_input("Do you have an existing account? 'Y/N'").lower()
  if user2=="y":
    existing_user=raw_input("Enter your username:")
    exisitng_pass=raw_input("Enter your password:")
    for passwords in f:
      if passwords==existing_user+":"+exisitng_pass:
        print "Welcome to your account" + " " + existing_user
        with open("money.py", "r") as m:
          info= int(m.readline().strip())
          useropt2=raw_input("Would you like to view your balance- enter 1, deposit money- enter 2, withdraw money- enter 3 or exit- enter 4:")
          if useropt2=="1":
            print "Your balance is:", info
          if useropt2=="2":
            amountdep= int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit?:"))
            a=info+int(amountdep)
            print "Your new balance is:", a
            with open("money.py", "w") as m:
                m.write(str(a))
          if useropt2=="3":
            amountwith=int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?:"))
            t=info-int(amountwith)
            print "Your balance is:", t
            with open("money.py", "w") as m:
              m.write(str(t))
```

I would like to know how I can create a loop to ask the user if he/she would like to choose another operation, such as the useropt variable after each time, one operation is complete. For instance at the end of each if statement where the user chooses a certain operation to do, I would like to know how I can ask the user again, if they would like to do another operation. Thanks.

Comment: Consider reading about functions in python.

Comment: I know about functions but am not sure how I can implement them in this program

Answer (score 0):

After you `import time` you could do:

```
running = True
while running:
    print "Welcome to the virtual banking system"

    #the rest of your code, indented by one.

    continue = raw_input("Would you like to do another operation? 'Y/N'").lower()
    running = continue == "y"
```

This will give the user an option to quit after every operation, but restart otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be structured otherwise, using a while loop and a function to handle input.

General example :

```
# this code should go after creating a new account/entering an existing one
while True:
    Ans = raw_input("what would you like to do? 1... 2... , -1 to exit")
    int code = ProcessAns(int(Ans))
    if code == -1:
        print "bye!"
        break



# and here the function that will be called every time
def ProcessAns(ans):
    if ans == 1: 
        # do stuff
    elif ans == 2: 
        # do other stuff

    # include a way to get out
    elif ans == -1:
        return -1
    return 1
```